# Is it possible to run CUDA C remotely?

Tags: ssh, cuda, remote-access, nvidia

I am new to CUDA C and I would like to have some have an answer to a question; I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a code that demands a pretty high computational cost: my Gpu is a Quadro k600 and takes about 15h in order to complete the calculations I need to do. I was wandering if there is a way to connect remotely to somebody else's computer in order to borrow a greater computational capacity in order to speed up the calculations; does Nvidia or some university provide that kind of service? should that be done by using ssh?

Comment: CUDA or OpenCL needs some host code to manage the kernel code (in CUDA or in OpenCL) running on the GPUs, so it is not possible the way you ask it.

Comment: Many universities in Europe have access to a national grid or even the European Grid Infrastructure. So if you're working in a university, ask your resource admins (or equivalent). If you're an amateur or professional you may be interested in renting a CUDA-capable private cloud or cluster (Amazon GPU instances, for example). If you already have access to a more powerful machine, just SSH into it.

Comment: @Basile_Starynkevitch Of course I have a host code... maybe i wasn't clear enough: i would like to run my code on another machine in order to speed up the time since my gpu is not fast enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the NVIDIA test drive program that you could sign up for and try a high end tesla.
http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-test-drive.html

If you are familiar with linux:
You can log into another persons computer with ssh (login and password is provided with test drive program)
Copy of your code with scp or rsync
Compile your code on their machine (this is likely necessary for compatibility reasons).
Copy over your data again with scp or rsync
Run on their machine
Copy back output data with scp/rsync

I frequently use ssh to log into computing clusters to run larger jobs than what my local machine would be able to use. If you do end up using a cluster, they should provide you with some documentation on how to submit jobs, as it is not quite as simple as using a workstation.

As previously mentioned, Amazon also offers you to buy computing time on CUDA enabled clusters. 
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/7249489223918169
may help if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

[rCUDA](http://www.rcuda.net/) might be what you are looking for